# Linear and bilinear constraint with Gurobi

Tags: r, gurobi

Looking at Gurobi's expamples for programs, there is one for [QCPs](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/qcp_r.html), and one for [bilinear](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/bilinear_r.html) programs, and I was wondering how to add a constraint that is linear and bilinear (sorry if there's specific jargon for such a problem) in R (or any other language, if easier, but I am using R). Specifically, how would I add a matrix of constraints of the form (for example) that

xz + y - yz < c

where c is some constant. I think I could use mccormick relaxation to re-write this as a linear program (right?), but I was wondering if Gurobi has easy syntax for such constraints?

My current understanding of the syntax for QCPs and bilinear programs is that you use a sparse matrix construction of the form

[image]

And so you cannot refer to x,y,z on their own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In case anyone else comes across a similar issue, you create a quadcon list and add it to the model, as [described here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/matlab_the_model_argument.html). For an illustration of using quadcon, it is quite similar to quadratic constraints in [this example](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/qcp_r.html), though this example is not explicitly of the type of constraint I asked about.